# Create Date from Filename SQL

Tags: sql-server, datetime

I have a database with a table of attachments. I need to sort the attachments by date, putting the old data plus date into a new table.
I do not have access to the files themselves, I want to create dates in this table based on the filename.

Desired output is YYYY MM DD. Not worried about HH, just going to set these as 0.

```
SELECT CONVERT(
            DATETIME, CONVERT(VARCHAR(40), '2015-03-20')
            , 120)
```

desired output like: 2015-03-20 00:00:00.000

I have tried a LEFT(RIGHT on the filename originally. However as there is sometimes extra characters or the date format is reversed, this isnt working.
I have tried some solutions from https://www.sqlservercentral.com/forums/topic/get-date-part-from-a-filename-string but once again the varied formatting of the filenames makes any of these solutions not work.

```
----try1:   
GO
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @S = '42223_bob_2015-03-20-022535.pdf'
--SET @S = '43661_bill_2015-04-29-113348 (1).pdf'
--SET @S = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-22-05-2017 12:09:27pm.xls'
--SET @S = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-2018-05-11-11-05-37.xls'

SELECT @S AS Filename
       , LEFT(RIGHT(@S,21),10) AS r21_l10
GO

----try2:
DECLARE
@Split CHAR(1)
,@X XML
, @S VARCHAR(MAX)

SET @S = '42223_bob_2015-03-20-022535.pdf'
--SET @S = '43661_bill_2015-04-29-113348 (1).pdf'
--SET @S = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-22-05-2017 12:09:27pm.xls'
--SET @S = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-2018-05-11-11-05-37.xls'

SET @Split = '-'

SELECT
@X = CONVERT(XML,'<root><s>' + REPLACE(@S,@Split,'</s><s>')+'</s></root>')
SET ROWCOUNT 1
SELECT
DateValue
FROM
(SELECT (CASE 
                 WHEN LEN(Value) = 8 AND ISDATE(Value) = 1 
                 THEN CAST(Value AS DATE)
         ELSE NULL
         END) AS DateValue
FROM (
          SELECT T.c.value('.','VARCHAR(MAX)') AS [Value] 
          FROM @X.nodes('/root/s') T (c)
    ) Result1
WHERE ISDATE(Value) = 1
) Result2
WHERE DateValue IS NOT NULL
ORDER BY DateValue DESC
SET ROWCOUNT 0
```

--solution courtesy of John Cappelletti

```
GO

/****** Object:  UserDefinedFunction [dbo].[fn_FileNameDateExtract]    
Script 
Date: 11/07/2019 15:16:23 PM ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

-- =============================================
-- Author:      John Cappelletti
-- =============================================
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fn_FileNameDateExtract]
(
@filename   NVARCHAR(MAX)
)
RETURNS
DATE
AS
BEGIN
SET @filename =
TRY_CONVERT(date,SUBSTRING(@filename
   ,COALESCE(
             NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',@filename),0)
            ,NULLIF(PATINDEX('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@filename),0)
    ),10));
RETURN @filename
END

GO
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps `patindex()` would help here.  We find the position of a string `####-##-##`, and then `try_convert()` to date

If the pattern is not matched, then a NULL value would be returned

**Example**

```
Declare @S varchar(200) = '42223_bob_2015-03-20-022535.pdf'

Select try_convert(date,substring(@S,nullif(patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',@S),0),10))
```

**Returns**

```
2015-03-20
```

> **EDIT - Updated for Alternate Pattern**

```
--Declare @S varchar(200) = '42223_bob_2015-03-20-022535.pdf'
Declare @S varchar(200) = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-22-05-2017 12:09:27pm.xls'

Set DateFormat DMY

Select try_convert(date,substring(@S
       ,coalesce(
                 nullif(patindex('%[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]%',@S),0)
                ,nullif(patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@S),0)
        ),10))
```

Comment: This sort of works, but only in certain scenarios. See 3rd SET for scenario3.
Declare @S varchar(200)

--SET @S = '42223_bob_2015-03-20-022535.pdf'
--SET @S = '43661_bill_2015-04-29-113348 (1).pdf'
SET @S = 'Invoice Revenue By Group-22-05-2017 12:09:27pm.xls'

I have tried another select with a different patindex based on your answer but scenrio1 also returns undesired results for 'Date_B'.

Select
  try_convert(date,substring(@S,nullif(patindex('%[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]%',@S),0),10)) as date_B

Comment: @ClientRelations See EDIT for Alternate Pattern

Comment: I have tried to create as a function, but the function does not like 'SET DateFormat DMY'.
I have edited the original post to include the function, is the SET DateFormat DMY required?

Comment: @ClientRelations Well done!  Missed that you were going with a function.